# How to run code when the browser window is resized in a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I am running some code on the [render event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_render_handler.htm) that decides whether or not some buttons related to scrolling are displayed depending on some element properties:

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

If a user resizes their browser window, I'd like to run the same code. But I do not see any component-level mechanism (such as an event) related to such resizing.

Is there an established pattern for responding to browser window resizes in Lightning Components?

(There is a [ui:resizeObserver](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/resizeObserver) in the open source but that hasn't made it into the set of supported components if this [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm) list is complete).

Comment: I think, for now, you need to listen to window.resize, and use $A.getCallback so you have a valid handler for modifying the component state.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

you can use

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

and you can check window.addEventListner to detect the resizing. Paste this code in your doInit JS controller method and check if it works.

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', $A.getCallback(function(){
        if(component.isValid()) {
            console.log('Resizing');
        }
    })); 
}
```