# How to detect window.resize event in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I want to change height of a `div` element of my aura component as the browser windows height gets changed. I am enable to find any event associated with window.resize. How do i call a method when user resizes the browser window.
Found a similar question but didn't understand it well.

[How to run code when the browser window is resized in a Lightning Component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201349/how-to-run-code-when-the-browser-window-is-resized-in-a-lightning-component)

Comment: Have you tri d using css media queries? Or add slds classes that will do that based on different screen sizes

Comment: @glls No in my use case the height of the div element is calculated dynamically as per the available screen space, so media query is not an option. I need to calculate the space available and assign to the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot execute a JS function directly in lightning. You can use another method to detect the window resizing effect. Try window.addEventListner

```
window.addEventListener('resize', $A.getCallback(function(){  }));
```

Use this code in your doInit controller method

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', $A.getCallback(function(){
        if(component.isValid()) {
            console.log('Resizing Window');
        }
    }));
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.